# How to callback ReCAPTCHA a object function?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

When I callback a object function like this

```
<button class="g-recaptcha"
        data-sitekey="xxxxx"
        data-callback="Obj.fn">
    Send
</button>
```

I have this error:

ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: Obj.fn

Comment: Recaptcha can't dig into your code like that. You need to make the `fn` global or available globally. You can try this in your js `window.GlobalFn = Obj.fn`. Then use GlobalFn in the `data-callback` attribute.